# Viewing a specific sheet within a workbook using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have my code for opening and gathering information from any sheet within the workbook, basically what it does it open the workbook, ask what sheet you want to pull info from, and it processes it. It then quits powershell and leaves excel open.

The only problem I have is that I would like powershell to actually show the sheet it is pulling from in the excel window. For instance if I choose sheet 3 to process info from, excel will by default show the last sheet I had selected and leave it, I would like it to go to a specific one. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the Activate() method.

```
$Excel = new-object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
[void]$Workbook.Worksheets.Add()
[void]$Workbook.Worksheets.Add()
$Workbook.Worksheets.Item(2).Activate()
$Excel.Visible = $true
```

That will open Excel, create a workbook, add two sheets, and then display the second sheet.

Comment: Thanks, I did a lot of searching but i couldn't seem to find it for it being so simple :P

Answer (score 1):

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.Visible = $true
$workbook = $excel.workbooks.open('D:\Projects\working\data.xlsm')
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item('Graph')
$sheet.activate()
$rangeSource=$sheet.range("A50","M73")
$rangeSource.Copy() | out-null
$Results = Get-Clipboard -TextFormatType Html | select -skip 7 | Out-String
```

Comment: Copying range data in excel sheet as HTML for email body

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).